# mysql query not saving the correct results in the variables

Tags: mysql

I've the following query:

```
select wall.postid from wall,posts where  
wall.postid = posts.postid and posts.userid=puserid
order by wall.postid desc LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0;
```

It returns results in the following manner.

```
  wall.postid
-----------------
      52
      51
      50
      49
```

Now I want to save the max value i.e 52 and min value i.e 49 in a variable so that I can use it in my next query.I am using the following query to do so.

```
select @upper:=max(wall.postid),@lower:=min(wall.postid) from wall,posts where  
wall.postid = posts.postid and posts.userid=puserid
order by wall.postid desc LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0;
```

I've but these variables save the max and min ids of the column not this result set.i.e
it returns me max = 52 and min = 41 which is the minimum value of the column.I need min = 49.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select @upper:=max(`postid`), @lower:=MIN(`postid`) 
from
(
select wall.postid from wall,posts where  
wall.postid = posts.postid and posts.userid=puserid
order by wall.postid desc LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0)m
```

Comment: hey thnx for the answer can you tell me how to only save those max and min value in a variable without returning the resultset.I want to run the query only one time like you have done above.because here the select statment will return the resultset i dont want that.

Comment: but the `select` will return me the result set.I want those variables to get populated and then use them in the next query to get the final result.This will return me an extra row with min,max value which will cause problem to me on my server side script.

Comment: @Mj1992: the above query should work.. you could also try select max(`postid`) into @upper from ....

Comment: oh I am sorry your answer is correct.I was not clear about my question actually I am using this as a prepare statement which I execute and when I execute I get the resultset due to the `select` keyword in your answer.So I only want the variables to get populated not the result set.So that I get only one resultset which will be returned by the query after this that will use these two variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the limit before the aggregation to get the results you want

```
 select
     @upper = max(postID),
     @lower = min(postID)
 from
 (
      select wall.postid from wall 
          inner join posts on wall.postid = posts.postid 
      where   
      posts.userid=puserid 
      order by wall.postid desc LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
 ) as v
```

Note also the improved ANSI-92 join syntax.